# Why do we define topology like this?

Tags: general-topology, definition

In the book "Topology" by James Munkres we define topology on a set $X$ like the following(page 76):

$\mathscr T$ is a topology on $X$ if:

- $\emptyset,X\in\mathscr T$
- $T\subset\mathscr T\implies\bigcup T\in\mathscr T$
- $T\subset\mathscr T\land T\mbox{ is finite}\implies \bigcap T\in\mathscr T$

Why does the third property have the fact that $T$ is finite? What does it gives us?

Comment: Because an infinite collection allows you to build a closed set from open sets, by intersection (for instance a single point from shrinking neighborhoods).

Comment: General definitions raise from concrete cases. If you take for example the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then you will see that it does not preserver infinite intersections. The infinite version of (3) just isnt useful.